# How to convert Object YYYYM1 YYYYM2 to Month and Year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a data set of trade statistics. The data is in the following form:

```
    reporter    partner         Time Period export          import
0   Argentina   United States   1990M2      1.304801e+08    5.984441e+07
1   Argentina   United States   1990M3      1.237417e+08    5.092350e+07
2   Argentina   United States   1990M4      1.020971e+08    4.884196e+07
3   Argentina   United States   1990M5      1.569232e+08    5.583000e+07
4   Argentina   United States   1990M6      1.539624e+08    6.869098e+07
5   Argentina   United States   1990M7      1.491639e+08    6.207464e+07
6   Argentina   United States   1990M8      1.675413e+08    8.482295e+07
7   Argentina   United States   1990M9      1.459988e+08    7.731452e+07
8   Argentina   United States   1990M10     1.613134e+08    1.061588e+08
9   Argentina   United States   1990M11     1.392604e+08    9.931942e+07
10  Argentina   United States   1990M12     1.266004e+08    1.003602e+08
11  Argentina   United States   1991M1      1.183864e+08    8.458743e+07
12  Argentina   United States   1991M2      1.107058e+08    7.544877e+07
13  Argentina   United States   1991M3      1.034667e+08    7.632608e+07
14  Argentina   United States   1991M4      1.078808e+08    9.906306e+07
```

and so on.

The "Time Period" variable is Dtype object. I want to change the format of the "Time Period" variable so that I get February 1990 instead of 1990M2, March 1990 instead of 1990M2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to datetime64 dtype using `pd.to_datetime` with a specified `format` and extract the year using the `dt` accessor. Ex:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Period'], format='%YM%m').dt.year
```

If you wish, you could also extract the month via `dt.month`. [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

---

Alternatively, you could split the strings on 'M' and cast to two separate columns of dtype int, e.g.

```
df[['Y','M']] = df["Time Period"].str.split("M", expand=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: extraction is not a problem. I used a naive method. 

`left = df['Time Period'].str[:4]
df['year'] = left`


This gives the same result as `pd.to_datetime`

Can't I just reformat the "Time Period" column without extracting Year and Month separately?

Comment: @dr_phd1: sure, added another option